# Conditional expectation $E(X_1 \mid \overline{X}_n)$ if $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d. Am I correct?

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, conditional-expectation

Conditional expectation $E(X_1 \mid \overline{X}_n)$ if $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d.

Since $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are i.i.d, then $E(X_1 \mid \overline{X}_n) = E(X_1)=\overline{X}_n$

Am I correct in thinking this? 
Thanks!

(Just to overclearify $\overline{X}_n$ is the sample mean)
Question is from Van Der Vaart: Asymptotic Statistics.

Comment: The answer from @SiongThyeGoh is right. Nevertheless, is not true that $\bar X_n=E(X_1)$ (and then is also not true that $E(X_1|\bar X_n)=E(X_1)$ ).

Check that $E(X_1|\bar X_n)$ and $\bar X_n$ are random variables (the same r.v., indeed), but $E(X_1)$ is a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$E(X_i |\bar{X}_n)= E(X_j |\bar{X}_n)$$

Summing them up $$\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i|\bar{X}_n)=E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|\bar{X}_n)=E(n\bar{X}_n|\bar{X}_n)=n\bar{X}_n$$

$$nE(X_1|\bar{X}_n)=n\bar{X}_n$$
Hence,
$$E(X_1|\bar{X}_n)=\bar{X}_n$$